# Downloading file with PHP. How to get FILENAME?

Tags: php, file, download, resolve

I need to download files from remote server with my PHP script. The problem is that the links I recieve look like "**example.com?download=12345**". So I want to save the file with **correct extension** and (at best) preserve it's **original filename.** How do I do this?
Thank you all!

Comment: It makes a huge difference what method you are using to do the file download. Are you using curl? Or 'get_file_contents or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EricLaw (of the IE Team) has posted a [detailed analysis of this on the IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-may-rename-downloaded-files-if-querystrings-are-present-or-if-run-from-cache.aspx) last November. While his post is focused on IE, the basics hold for most browsers:

- use a Content-Disposition header (cleanest, standard-compliant, allows you to specify the filename; can be combined with either of the following)
- don't use a query-string (not always practical - but possible with URL rewriting)
- "Add a bogus querystring parameter at the end with the desired extension" (a bit of a hack, but works)

However, the source server is not obliged to do any of this; the most likely option would be the `Content-Disposition` header. If that is not present, you are back to square 1 (although you could guesstimate the file type from its content).

Answer (score 8):

The `Content-Disposition` header in the HTTP response, if it exists, will contain the filename the other server wants the file to have.

Comment: +1.  Also, the server does not *need* to add the `Content-Disposition` header, so you should always check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using curl, the response header should return the actual filename. The header for file downloads looks like:

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'
```

Comment: Managed to get header from its response by using some curl wrapper class! Thank you all!