# download file to my server with php with a url without file name

Tags: php, file, download

I can download a csv file via a fixed url. The url just doesn't have a file name.
When I open the url in a browser, the file export.csv is generated and after about 10 sec the download starts.
Now I want to download this export csv file directly to my own server,

I have the code below, but it doesn't work in my case.
Can you help me? my thanks are big

```
<?php
  
    
    $url = 
    'https://www.example.com/product-export/link123456789';
      
   
    $file_name = basename($url);
      
   
    if (file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($url)))
    {
        echo "File downloaded successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "File downloading failed.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: i trigger the download by a cronjob

Comment: unfortunately I can't make the link public

Comment: The server might be offering a file name in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5195916/231316) header

Comment: the generated output filename is always export.csv

Answer (score 0):

As the generated output filename is always export.csv, we may use the following to specify the filename:

```
$file_name = dirname(__FILE__) . "/export.csv";
```

(make sure the directory is write-permitted so that the php can save the file "export.csv")

Hence, the code will be:

```
<?php
      
  $url = 'http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/export1a.csv';
         
//$file_name = basename($url);
  
  $file_name = dirname(__FILE__) . "/export.csv";    
   

  if (file_put_contents($file_name, file_get_contents($url))) {
        echo "File downloaded successfully";
        } else {
        echo "File downloading failed.";
    }
?>
```

For your cronjob, it will be something like :

```
1 1 * * * php /path_to_the_php/test.php
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. get as result File downloading failed. a file has been created (export.csv) but it is empty

Comment: Please see my revised answer --- use EXACTLY the code , including the $url , paste it as a PHP in your server and run it to see the result. It works for sure (make sure the directory is write-permitted so that the php can save the file "export.csv")

Comment: Thanks, with your test url (http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/export1a.csv) it works, but it also has a file name in the url. With the url I have to use I get this error: PHP Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.example.com/product-export/link123456789): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
in /var/www/vhosts/myownexample.com/import/test.php on line 10

Comment: if possible pls tell us the real link so that we  can further check

Comment: Hi, I'm not allowed to make it public online. can I email it to you?